# Refresh Div on Parent Page from Child Overlay

Tags: jquery

I have a page called menu.php that opens a jQuery Tools overlay window from a div called #menulist.  This window loads content from a **different** page (editmenu.php).  The editmenu.php does some ajax, etc..

When its done (on Success), however, is there a way to have the editmenu.php page refresh the DIV #menulist (on menu.php page) without refreshing the entire menu.php page?  Right now I am using:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

But that refreshes the entire page.  Not what I am looking for.

I have done this before using iFrames, but want to avoid that extra step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#menulist').load('menu.php');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Lance. I just did that on the onClose event from the parent page.  Worked like a charm.  Darin, yeah, had never thought about it, but here is my Accept mark...